# Grid of sections with sub grid that is either vertical if it fits or horizontal if it does not fit

Tags: html, css

This is NOT a CSS grid question (though if CSS grid solves it then great. I don't think CSS grid would solve it though).

I have content that is 1 to N tall rectangles of data followed by 5 or more short rectangles of data.  Currently it's displayed like this if the screen wide enough for 5 across

```
+--+ +--+ +--+
|  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  |
+--+ +--+ +--+

+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
|  | |  | |  | |  | |  |
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
```

As the screen gets less wide it will collapse like this

```
+--+ +--+
|  | |  |
|  | |  |
|  | |  |
|  | |  |
+--+ +--+

+--+
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
+--+

+--+ +--+
|  | |  |
+--+ +--+

+--+ +--+
|  | |  |
+--+ +--+

+--+
|  |
+--+
```

And eventually go to 1 column

I'd like to change it do this when wide enough for 5 columns

(goal)

```
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
|  | |  | |  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  | +--+ +--+
|  | |  | |  | 
|  | |  | |  | +--+ +--+
+--+ +--+ +--+ |  | |  |
               +--+ +--+

               +--+
               |  |
               +--+
```

If it was ultra-wide this would be fine too

```
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
|  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  | +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
|  | |  | |  | 
|  | |  | |  | 
+--+ +--+ +--+
```

Note: there are no pixel sizes and no known widths.

Here's a repo of what I have at the moment

```css
#sections {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: start;
}
.tall {
  background-color: #ccf;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
#shorts {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 0;
}
.short {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fcc;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="sections">
    <div class="tall">t<br>a<br>l<br>l<br></div>
    <div class="tall">t<br>a<br>l<br>l<br></div>
    <div class="tall">t<br>a<br>l<br>l<br></div>
    <div id="shorts">
      <div class="short">s</div>
      <div class="short">s</div>
      <div class="short">s</div>
      <div class="short">s</div>
      <div class="short">s</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to size the window to see the layout change.

This doesn't achieve the goal above. Instead, if the screen is not wide enough for 8 sections it puts all last 5 short ones below the tall ones. Smaller than that and they collapse as expected.  Media queries are not a solution since I don't know the size of the sections.  Also note: I want the small areas to stay together. I don't want some of them right of tall and some below (could do that by making everything an inline-block I think).

In fact if there was only room for 4 across then I'd want this

```
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
|  | |  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  | +--+
|  | |  | |  | 
|  | |  | |  | +--+
+--+ +--+ +--+ |  |
               +--+

               +--+
               |  |
               +--+

               +--+
               |  |
               +--+

               +--+
               |  |
               +--+
```

It bears repeating that the number of tall and short sections is unknown but 1-3 tall and 4-7 short is a normal range. I just chose 3 tall and 5 short as an example.

Also, in the examples above, tall is about twice as tall as short but in the actual code, tall is 7x as tall as short. So stacking them as in the last example works out better than the diagram.

Is there a way to achieve the goal having set of small elements collapse on the right until none will fit (CSS only)?

Comment: You do need at least one media query because _something_ has to decide when the short boxes wrap under the tall ones. Your logic isn't achievable without minimal constraint.

Comment: Can't use a media query because the size of any element is undefined. Normal inline-elements flow just fine, without a media query. It's only the fact that I want the small elements to form a grid and that they're all a non-uniform size that makes what I'm trying to do anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `flex-basis: min-content;flex-grow: 1;` is enough for what you want. `min-content` is to consider the width of one short element, you can also try `0` for a slightly different effect.

```css
#sections {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: start;
}
.tall {
  background-color: #ccf;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
}
#shorts {
  flex-basis: min-content;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 0;
}
.short {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="sections">
    <div class="tall">t<br>a<br>l<br>l<br></div>
    <div class="tall">t<br>a<br>l<br>l<br></div>
    <div class="tall">t<br>a<br>l<br>l<br></div>
    <div id="shorts">
      <div class="short">s</div>
      <div class="short">s</div>
      <div class="short">s</div>
      <div class="short">s</div>
      <div class="short">s</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sigh .. This always seems to happen when I ask a CSS question. I try to pair down my code an MCVE, a solution is posted (thank you! ) but then it doesn't actually fit because something was lost in my translation to MCVE.  I think what I'm trying to do might be impossible. I want all the small items to be the same width for any column they show up in where as if they are 5 across I don't care what width they are. But there's no way to enforce same width (width of largest element in column) because they aren't actually columns when they wrap, they're rows. Maybe turning 'shorts' into a grid 

Comment: So I think I figured out what I was trying to do is not supported. Effectively I was trying to have a responsive table. I wanted items to flow into rows but stay a grid. The problem if this was actually supported it would insert elements into the first row, when one doesn't fit it puts it in the 2nd row. But, if the size of that element is larger than the 1st element in the 1st row then the 1st column needs to be wider. Making it wider might make the last element(s) no longer fit so then they need to be moved to the 2nd row. Repeat for all elements. TPTB don't like such unbounded complexity.